# howto paginate my search result in handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

When i search---products are displaying..but when i click on page 2 it gets error...how can i paginate the search results in handlebars..

This is my search route.

```
router.get('/products-search',function(req,res,next){
    const perPage = 1;
    const page = req.query.page || 1;
    const title = "Ahl.com: "+ req.query['search'];
    Product.find({"tags" : {"$regex": req.query['search'], "$options": "i"}}).sort('-date').skip((perPage * page) - perPage).limit(perPage)
    .then(products => {
        Product.countDocuments({"tags" : {"$regex": req.query['search'], "$options": "i"}}).then(productCount=>{
            res.render("categories/search", {title:title , products:products , current: parseInt(page), pages:Math.ceil(productCount / perPage)});
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("Search err"));
```

})

my handlebar helper for pagination

```
paginate: function(options){
        let output = "";

        if(options.hash.current === 1){
            output += `<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">F</a></li>`;
        }else{
            output += `<li class="page-item"><a href="?page=1" class="page-link">F</a></li>`;
        }

        let i = (Number(options.hash.current) > 5 ? Number(options.hash.current) - 4 : 1);

        if(i !== 1){
            output += `<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">....</a></li>`;
        }

        for(; i <= (Number(options.hash.current) + 4) && i <= options.hash.pages; i++){
            if(i === options.hash.current){
                output += `<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">${i}</a></li>`;
            }else{
                output += `<li class="page-item"><a href="?page=${i}" class="page-link">${i}</a></li>`;
            }
            if(i === Number(options.hash.current) + 4 && i < options.hash.pages){
                output += `<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">....</a></li>`;
            }
        }

        if(options.hash.current === options.hash.pages){
            output += `<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">L</a></li>`;
        }else{
            output += `<li class="page-item"><a href="?page=${options.hash.pages}" class="page-link">L</a></li>`;
        }

        return output;
    }
```

pagination links

```
<div class="container">
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="flex-wrap pagination">
        {{#paginate current=current pages=pages}}{{/paginate}}

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do paginating, filtering and sorting of tasks, i send a page array with page number, limit and skip for each element:

```
router.get('/tasks', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const match = {};
    const sort = {};
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    const skip = parseInt(req.query.skip);

    if (req.query.completed) {
        match.completed = req.query.completed === 'true';
    }

    if (req.query.sortBy) {
        const parts = req.query.sortBy.split(":");
        sort[parts[0]] = parts[1] === 'desc'? -1 : 1;
    }

    try {
        await req.user.populate('tasks').execPopulate({
            path: 'tasks',
            match,
            options: {
                sort,
                limit,
                skip
            }
        });
        
        const totalTasks = await Task.countDocuments({ owner: req.user._id }); 

        const pages = Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(totalTasks / limit) },(v, idx) => {
            return {
                num: idx + 1,
                limit,
                skip: (limit * (idx + 1)) - limit
            }
        });

        res.render('tasks', {
            tasks: req.user.tasks,
            enablePaging: totalTasks > limit,
            pages,
            limit
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

In the hbs template i iterate through pages array using each helper:

```
        {{#if enablePaging}}
        <div class="tasksPaging">
            Pages:
            {{#each pages}}
            <a href="/tasks?limit={{limit}}&skip={{skip}}">
                {{num}}
            </a>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        {{/if}}

        <ul id="taskList">
            {{#each tasks}}
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" {{#if completed }} checked="checked" {{/if}} onclick="toggleTask('{{ _id }}', {{ completed }})">
                    <input type="text" value="{{ description }}" onchange="updateTask('{{ _id }}', this)">
                    <button onclick="deleteTask('{{ _id }}')" class="deleteBtn">
                        x
                    </button>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
```

And this is how it looks when i access /tasks?limit=4
[image: Task manager]